# Why are diffuse white highlights on matte objects as bright as they are?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light

The reason we can see the color of objects is light rays undergo scattering in the subsurface of a material, and in their walk in the material lose some wavelengths, and finally exit at a random direction ([link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection))

However, aside from this, you see white highlights on an object from the light source. These can be diffuse or specular depending on surface roughness (I'm assuming they're both from surface interactions)

[image]

Look at the highlights on the shoulder here for what I mean. Not where the arrow is pointing.

However, I just found that that aside from metal, most common surfaces, even when highly polished, specularly reflect only a few percent of the incident radiation. How are these highlights then so pronounced, especially for the diffuse highlight case where the light is distributed in all directions.

Comment: Humans can even see individual photons in the right conditions. Why would we not be able to see weak-but-visible specular reflections?

Comment: @HiddenBabel But they don't necessarily appear that weak compared to the intensity of the subsurface diffused reflection(i.e a few percent of the intensity). Even when taking a photograph, they are clearly visible in an ordinary exposure

Comment: I used outdoors as an example, but anywhere near a light source you'll see this

Comment: I guess one thing to consider is that the light from these two types of reflections is additive, so you're going to notice a localized spot that's brighter, even if the difference is not drastic. The other thing that the Wikipedia article you linked to says is that the amount of specular reflection can depend on the angle, so you may get a different percentage around creases and near the silhouette. Also, it's difficult to judge from images; in your photo, the person may be backlit (direct illumination coming from up and behind), and the front may be just light reflected off of the environment

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Indeed, in addition a photo may be re-touched with image editors like photoshop by blurring regions, changing contrast of image parts and etc.

Comment: _The reason we can see the color of objects is light rays undergo scattering in the subsurface of a material_ No. The reason why we see colors is that surfaces absorbs part of incident EM spectrum and reflects other part(s). The reflected part of spectral composition gives color effect when interpreted by our brains.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas You ignored the second part of my statement which addressed this. The Wikipedia article I linked discussed that in the "colour of objects" section

Comment: "most common surfaces, even when highly polished, specularly reflect only a few percent of the incident radiation".
Do you have a reference for this? Also, just realize that when looking at something at a low angle, you look at light coming from a large area, but you see a small solid angle, ie, a 1x1m² seen from 80° will be just a small little fraction when compared to head on (0°). If you imagine a perfect scatterer, scattering uniformly in every direction, the 80° would appear brighter from the same distance. This combined with much higher reflectivity at higher AOI, gives that appearance

Comment: @JoséAndrade It's a quote directly from the link I provided

Comment: Found the link and read it, nonetheless, I find that somewhat misleading, first because its too un-precise, second, I am not entirely sure of that claim, specially when then backing it up by saying "a lake is a special case": no, just no. But coming back to your problem: "A few percent" tells little about apparent brightness. going from say 4% reflection at 0° to 16% at 80° means a gain, in photography terms, of 2EV. That is a lot. Of course this might be in the wrong scale of things, but there is definitely an increase at higher AOIs, and you need to compare relative values, not absolute.

Comment: The reason why I do not like that claim, is because you need to first define polish level: if you polish something to the optics community standards for mirrored surfaces, I can guarantee, that most materials will approach 100% specular reflectivity at 90° incidence. That is nothing else than application of fresnel eqs, which are precise.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Interesting. The polish level they have defined as "perfect polish", so something like the limiting case. But according to you, at that level of polish, light simply does not penetrate the material, like in the case of metal. So maybe the claim is incorrect then. What would you estimate is the percent reflection for a "regular" glossy material that you might encounter day to day, or a reasonable range to expect?

Comment: @JoséAndrade The increasing angle argument may apply for specular reflections, but when the surface is rough, the angle of incidence at some irregularity won't necessarily be the same as the angle of the beam with the surface

Comment: @xasthor On average of course it counts. Do not forget that at low viewing angles most light comes from high-number of specular reflections/scattering, while from high viewing angles, besides a much higher of reflectivity per reflection, you have a much higher chance of a low-number of reflections/scattering. Imagine a surface with a perfect distribution of facets between 0 and 90°. At low viewing angles, few order reflections mean at least one close to 0° reflections which will probably be around 4%, while at high angles most reflections will be at grazing incidence with reflectivities>60%

Comment: @JoséAndrade Not sure I completely understand what you said if I'm being frank. One thing though can we confirm, that these diffuse white highlights are a result of interactions of light at the surface of rough surfaces, and aren't the result of a subsurface scattering mechanism like discussed above that gives rise to color?

Comment: Yes. As you look to any surface at a grazing angle, they always reflect the light of the background source, so white light, remains white (i guess everyone looked at tables etc. at low angles and seen this). As all materials display 100% reflection at 90°, it also becomes color independent.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Then the same applies for all the angles in between as well right? Because diffuse reflections have the same intensity in all directions i.e regardless of where you observe them from

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing in the photo is specular reflection from the surface of fibers in the shoulder area. That component of the light coming off of the shirt is white. Plus, the amount of such specular reflection increases with angle of incidence from the normal. You can convince yourself of this using a flashlight and a piece of fabric laid flat on a table, always keeping the angle of incidence = angle of reflection. For low angles, i.e. the light almost perpendicular to the surface, the amount of reflected light is much less than for glancing angles.

Comment: But something that is just a few percent of the incident radiation, even if increased somewhat by the right angle - how can it be so pronounced, especially considering the fact that on a rough surface it is being distributed in all directions

Comment: @xasthor - well, how do you know it only "increased somewhat" due to the angle? It could be that it increases *dramatically* at a certain threshold angle.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović  Fair enough, that's possible.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović However, for reflection from a rough surface, light won't necessarily be reflected at that angle since the angle of incidence on some irregularity won't be the same as that it makes with the surface as a whole

Comment: @xasthor  It's only "a few percent" at normal incidence but increases with angle. Look up Fresnel's Equations. For a rough surface such as a fabric on a table there are still many fibers lying flat or close to flat (depends on type of fabric). Try what I suggested with a flashlight keeping angle of incidence = angle of viewing (reflection).

Comment: @Not_Einstein The fibres themselves have irregularities. But what you said does make sense and is plausible i.e that the flat irregularities contribute to a higher percent, and perhaps if you average out over the irregularities there's a net greater than a few percent reflection. But this feels speculative

Comment: @xasthor  There are different types of fibers which will show different degrees of the effect because the fibers are more or less randomly oriented. But again I suggest to just do the experiment and let us know what you find.

Comment: @Not_Einstein The reason I'm questioning it is only because diffuse reflections are supposed to have an equal intensity in all directions, i.e invariant of the viewing angle.

Comment: @xasthor  If you stood to the left of the person in your image there would be light from the shoulder scattered in your direction. That would be the diffuse component if the light were behind the person. A lot depends on the type of fabric. Google "images of woven fabrics" and you will see that there are straight runs of yarn laid down fairly flat so the front surface reflection from the fabric has some mirror-like properties.

Comment: @xasthor "The reason I'm questioning it is only because diffuse reflections are supposed to have an equal intensity in all directions" - that's a simplified/idealized model where you have a Lambertian diffuse "component", a separate specular "component", a subsurface scattering "component", etc. Real materials (including fibers) are more complicated than that; and contain layers, and substructures, and coating, and whatnot, and may reflect light in an anisotropic way - and all of these things contribute to the final appearance.

Comment: @xasthor P.S. This is why, to get realistic-looking results in CGI, a number of these idealized shaders are layered on top of one another in some way (either by tweaking built-in parameters like "clearcoat", "roughness", "sheen", "anisotopy", or by combining shaders and materials manually), and why textures are used to vary the reflective properties of the surface, etc.